# How to get root priviledges on ZTE Grand X Max 2?

Tags: rooting

This is a newer model with Cricket and I found no recovery image (CWM or TWRP) to flash yet. ADB-fastboot connection is achieved but only basic commands work (I just learned this stuff yesterday). I have not achieved the "white" screen of the bootloader, only a reboot to Android. Though I can get to the recovery menu this way and with volume up/power key combo. (I wouldn't know what to do next anyway at this point). There are some great solutions out there, but this model is not on their list. I've researched "one-click" download sites and poured through lots of Xda forums. It looks like a waiting game for a flash/root combo (TWRP and SuperSU). Now I'm looking to find the root files (su binaries?) to push into this model?

Comment: I found this website on rooting the ZTE Grand X Max 2. I hope this helps. http://kidapso.com/how-to-root-zte-grand-x-max-2/